# PHP Functions - Comparison error

Tags: php

I am getting an error trying to run the following code. Can you help me fixing this?

```
   if((invite_limit($id_usr) >= 2)||(pending_users() == ' ')){ 

         echo '<div class="new_ativa_off">';
         echo '<div class="new_qtd">0</div>';

         echo '<div class="new_txt">Pending</div>';
         echo '</div>';

   }else{

         echo '<div class="new_ativa" id="nu_open">';
         echo '<div class="new_qtd">';
         if($inactive_users >= 2){echo '2';}else{echo $inactive_users;}
         echo '</div>';

         echo '<div class="new_txt">Pending</div>';
         echo '</div>';
   }
```

**This is the pending users function >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
This is the pending users function >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

```
    function pending_users(){

    include('_config.php');

    if ($stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tb_user WHERE $user_adate  !=? AND $user_ref =?")) {


                        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nada, $nada);

                        $nada = '';

                        $stmt->execute();

                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $inactive_users = $stmt->num_rows;

                        $stmt->close();

                        echo $inactive_users;

                        $conex->close();
                    }

}
```

**invite limit function >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
invite limit function >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

```
    function invite_limit($id_usr){ 


            include('_config.php');
            if ($stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tb_user WHERE $user_ref =? AND DATE($user_refdate) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND DATE($user_refdate) <= NOW()")) {

                            $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_usr);

                            $stmt->execute();

                            $stmt->store_result();
                            $activations = $stmt->num_rows;

                            $stmt->close();

                            echo $activations;
                        }

            $conex->close();

    }
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: it's echoing the result instead of comparing

Comment: Provide the error message and a sample output of your two custom functions.

Comment: you should also post the code for the functions then. are you echoing in the functions or returning?

Comment: So what's the result?  Have you turned on error reporting?  We can't help you unless you provide more than what you provided.  Provide us with more of an insight to your problem and provide more code so that we can help you figure it out.

Comment: I've just pasted the code with the html. It's is a btn with the number of pending users on it. If there is 2 or more pendings it shows 2. If I have already activated 2 users today, the btn if off

Comment: I mean paste the code for these 2 functions: `invite_limit($id_usr)` and `pending_users()` - also couldn't hurt to post the actual output from this comparison.

Comment: Sorry how can I format the code?

Comment: highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the editor. If that fails, just post it and I'll edit it

Comment: ok answered. let me know how that goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's because you are echoing in your functions instead of returning. 
Remember even calling a function in a comparison will actually run the function as it is told to do. In this case, it is echoing and invalidating the comparison.

Try this:

```
function pending_users(){

    include('_config.php');
    if ($stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tb_user WHERE $user_adate  !=? AND $user_ref =?")) {

        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nada, $nada);

        $nada = '';

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();
        $inactive_users = $stmt->num_rows;

        $stmt->close();
        $conex->close();
        return $inactive_users;

    }
}
function invite_limit($id_usr){ 

    include('_config.php');
    if ($stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tb_user WHERE $user_ref =? AND DATE($user_refdate) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND DATE($user_refdate) <= NOW()")) {

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_usr);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();
        $activations = $stmt->num_rows;

        $stmt->close();
        $conex->close();
        return $activations;
    }
}
```

Also, close your connections before returning. Once you return on a function it no longer processes past that line.